# Sharepoint hub site totally blank on Internet Explorer browser - works on Chrome and Safari

Tags: sharepoint-online, internet-explorer, browsers

Sharepoint hub site totally blank on Internet Explorer browser. It appears for a couple of seconds and then goes blank - the site appears normal on Chrome and Safari.

I can get my other sites to come up, but not hub site.

This is the case for multiple users. Anyone know what is going on?[image]

Comment: Add your SP sites IE settings-> Trusted sites -> Local Intranet

Comment: it already is in trusted sites